# Mysql Stored Procedure no load no result

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I started on stored procedures with MySQL PHPMyAdmin 5.5 3.4 after watching the tutorial found on this site I took this example ([the tutorial siteduzero](http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/procedure-stockee/exemples-19))

I reproduced the same result without

The problem is that the process is slow in execution, it continues loading without displaying results after 2 min I close the page, creating the procedure is done correctly. Here's the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AfficherMarques`(OUT `Marques` VARCHAR(25))

BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Marques VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE pointeur CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT marque FROM marchands GROUP BY marque;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
OPEN pointeur;

    REPEAT
        FETCH pointeur INTO Marques;
                IF done = 0 THEN
                    SELECT Marques;
                END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE pointeur;

END
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried calling the procedure using the MySQL command line client instead?  As written, this proc is going to return a separate result-set for each iteration of the `REPEAT` loop and some versions of phpMyAdmin do not handle multiple results from procedures correctly.